# Number of poles of an algebraic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know much about complex analysis, so I'm not sure if this has an obvious answer or not. I am reading a paper and got stuck on a parenthetical comment.

$w(z)$ is a meromorphic function on some simply connected open subset $U\subset \mathbb{C}$, satisfying a polynomial equation in two variables $P(z,w)=0$ over the field of rational functions $\mathbb{C}(t)$. Once this conclusion is reached, the author states in parentheses, "so it has only finitely many poles". I'm not sure why this is true, and I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "complex function which is algebraic"?  A definition would help here.  Cheers!

Comment: Edited the original question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that we can write $P(z,w) = f_n(z) w^n + \ldots + f_1(z)w + f_0(z)$ where $f_i$ are some polynomials in $z$ so $\frac{P(z,w)}{w^n} = f_n(z) + \frac{f_{n-1}(z)}{w} + \ldots + \frac{f_0(z)}{w^n}$. $w$ having a pole means that $|w|\to \infty$ as we approach this point.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will try coming up with a solution using this.

Comment: So, can we just define $\frac{1}{w}(z_\alpha):=0$ for poles $z_\alpha$ of $w$, and then if $w$ had infinitely many poles, $f_n(z)$ would have infinitely many roots since $P(z,w)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(z,w)$ is a polynomial we can write

$$P(z,w) = f_n(z)w^n + \ldots + f_1(z) w + f_0(z)$$

where $\{f_i(z)\}_{i=0}^n$ are some polynomials with $f_n(z)\not\equiv 0$. Let $z_*$ be a pole of $w$, then $\lim_{z\to z_*} \frac{1}{w} = 0$ so if we divide $P$ by $w^n$ and take the limit $z\to z_*$ we find

$$0 = \lim_{z\to z_*}\frac{P(z,w)}{w^n} = \lim_{z\to z_*} \left(f_n(z) + \frac{f_{n-1}(z)}{w} + \ldots + \frac{f_0(z)}{w^n}\right) = f_n(z_*)$$

The polynomial $f_n(z)$ has a finite number of roots and $w$ therefore has a finite number of poles.